# Unexpected behavior when copying a Piecewise expression

Tags: front-end, piecewise

When I type a `Piecewise` function (e.g. `Piecewise[{{a,0<a<1},{2a,1<a<2}}]`) in mathematica notebook using `StandardForm` and try to copy the obtained (2-dimensional) expression (for use in some other program) by simply selecting and copying it, it copies the underlying box structure, instead of coping the expression in `InputForm`, as one would expect. At very least I did not expect to have the underlying box structure copied. When I copy the expression in `InputForm` it gets copied as expected. Could someone verify this and if this is the expected behavior?

```
$Version
```

> `"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"`

Comment: It's not a bug.  use Copy As > Input Text from Edit menu or the context menu.

Comment: @m_goldberg  Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: It's been the standard behavior for a long as can remember -- for at least 10 years.

Comment: @m_goldberg but when you copy for example `1/x` in standard form, and paste it for example here in mma se, you get `1/x` in input form, without the boxes. Basically  you get fraction with forward slash instead of one over x as is mathematical form.

Comment: You are expecting a degree of consistency from the input editor that I'm afraid it doesn't have,